# automated co-registration of PET CT

Tags: brain, neuroimaging

Hi all:) I've acquired Whole body PET CT data from form which I would like to generate brain co-registered PET and CT nifti files - has anyone implemented something similar? I have experience with fMRI preprocessing - could SPM do the trick?
Thanks!